# Detectar dirección de evento mousewheel en elemento con overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

El problema que presento se da gracias a que estoy realizado una pagina con `overflow: hidden` en la que las secciones están posicionadas en `absolute` fuera de la vista de la ventana y necesito que al hacer scroll estas animen el `top` con otros parámetros. Parecido al efecto del plugin [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). Pero dado al avanzado estado del diseño de esta, desearía seguir trabajando sin este plugin. Ahora, todo lo resolví momentáneamente llamando a un evento `.on("mousewheel")` ya que como el `overflow` de todo el body esta determinado a `hidden`, el evento `.scroll()` no funciona para lo que quiero realizar. Volviendo al anterior evento, llamo a la unidad del mismo, `e.deltaY` que me devuelve una representación del deslizamiento vertical de la rueda del mouse con un valor de 100 o -100 (en pocas palabras un buleano).

Al intentar crear casos de aplicación para activar eventos según en que sección se encuentre y animar, la sección actual, la previa y la próxima; cree una variable que me arroja el string "up" y "down" y otra variable global que me indica en que sección esta el mouse actualmente escuchándolo por el nombre de su `id` y compilado se ejecuta de esta manera:

```js
var HOVER_SECTION;
var BORDER;

$("section").mouseenter(function(){

 HOVER_SECTION = $(this).attr("id");
  BORDER = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

});

$(".mainwrapper").bind('mousewheel', function(event){

console.log(HOVER_SECTION)
var scrolldirection = false;

 if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta <= 0){
   
    scrolldirection = "down"; 
  
  }else {
  
   scrolldirection = "up";
  
  }
  
  console.log(scrolldirection);
   
   if (scrolldirection == "down" && BORDER != "borderBottom"){
  
   $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).animate({
    
     top: "-100%"
    
    });
    $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).next().animate({
    
     bottom: "0px"
    
    });
  
  }else if(scrolldirection == "up" && BORDER != "borderTop") {
  
   $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).animate({
    
     bottom: "-100%"
    
    });
    $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).prev().animate({
    
     top: "0px"
    
    });
  
  }
 
});
```

```css
* {
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

.mainwrapper {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  
  }
  
  .mainwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    
    width: 0px;
    
  }
  
  
  section {
    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  
  section h1 {
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
  }
  
  #section1 {
    
    background-color: aqua;
    
  }
  
  .underSection{
    
    background-color: purple;
    bottom: -100%;
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <section class="borderTop" id="section1">
    <h1>Seccion 1!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="underSection" id="section2">
    <h1>Seccion 2!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="underSection" id="section3">
    <h1>Seccion 3!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="borderBottom underSection" id="section4">
    <h1>Seccion 4!</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Al agregar solo dos elementos, se comporta de la forma deseada, pero al agregar tres o cuatro elementos, se descontrola y crashea, al intentar subir y bajar repetidas veces... Ahora, la pregunta es, ¿como podría arreglarlo? o ¿como podría hacerlo sin una librería externa? he intentado hasta donde mis conocimientos me limitan y siguiendo diferentes lógicas, pero aun así no hallo que funcione como lo quiero, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale a quien pueda interesar, el problema es simple, lo descubrí viendo a fondo las posiciones reales de los elementos en el DOM, pasa que solo hay que manejarlo con un atributo css, o es `top` o es `bottom` ya que si se maneja con los dos se crea un aberración al Js querer asignarle los dos valores a los elementos adyacentes a los bordes, ya que solo con los elementos actuales, previos o siguientes es posible asignarlos, puesto que se eliminan los atributos, pero con los que están sobre esos se le quedan las dos posiciones. Entonces lo que hice fue cambiar el `bottom: -100%` a `top: 100%` y todo arreglado, aquí hay una muestra funcional.

```js
var HOVER_SECTION;
var BORDER;

$("section").mouseenter(function(){

 HOVER_SECTION = $(this).attr("id");
  BORDER = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];

});

$(".mainwrapper").bind('mousewheel', function(event){

console.log(HOVER_SECTION)
var scrolldirection = false;

 if(event.originalEvent.wheelDelta <= 0){
   
    scrolldirection = "down"; 
  
  }else {
  
   scrolldirection = "up";
  
  }
  
  console.log(scrolldirection);
   
   if (scrolldirection == "down" && BORDER != "borderBottom"){
  
   $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).animate({
    
     top: "-100%"
    
    });
    $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).next().animate({
    
    //------cambio------
    
     top: "0px"
    
    });
  
  }else if(scrolldirection == "up" && BORDER != "borderTop") {
  
   $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).animate({
    
    //------cambio------
    
     top: "100%"
    
    });
    $("#"+HOVER_SECTION).prev().animate({
    
     top: "0px"
    
    });
  
  }
 
});
```

```css
* {
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
}

.mainwrapper {
  
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  
  }
  
  .mainwrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    
    width: 0px;
    
  }
  
  
  section {
    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  
  section h1 {
    
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
  }
  
  #section1 {
    
    background-color: aqua;
    
  }
  
  .underSection{
    
    background-color: purple;
    
    /*-----cambio-----*/
    
    top: 100%;
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainwrapper">
  <section class="borderTop" id="section1">
    <h1>Seccion 1!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="underSection" id="section2">
    <h1>Seccion 2!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="underSection" id="section3">
    <h1>Seccion 3!</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="borderBottom underSection" id="section4">
    <h1>Seccion 4!</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```